# Bad Header Request Error for "content-type: application/*+json"

Tags: curl, zoho-deluge

I am writing an API integration using Zoho Creator and could use a bit of guidance on framing the curl expressions correctly when invoking the API.
The below code is in curl and works perfectly when tested:

```
curl --request POST \
     --url https://horti-api.priva.com/api/sites/[site_id]/data \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'authorization: Bearer [access token***]' \
     --header 'content-type: application/*+json' \
     --header 'x-api-version: 2.0' \
     --data '
{
  "startTime": "2023-08-26T08:00:00Z",
  "endTime": "2023-08-26T12:00:00Z",
  "datapoints": [
    {
      "variableId": "80000005-0001-0001-0000-000080000bcc",
      "deviceId": "priva-1919980588",
      "deviceGroupId": "none"
    }
  ]
}
'
```

However, when I write this for Zoho Creator, I receive a bad header request error:

```
token = Access_Tokens[ID!=null].Token;
headers = map();
headers.put("accept", "application/json");
headers.put("authorization", "Bearer " + token);
headers.put("content-type","application/*+json");
headers.put("x-api-version", "2.0");
datapoints = list();
datapoint = map();
datapoint.put("variableId", "80000005-0001-0001-0000-000080000bcc" );
datapoint.put("deviceId", "priva-191998058");
datapoint.put( "deviceGroupId", "none");
datapoints.add(datapoint);
data = map();
data.put("startTime", "2023-08-26T08:00:00Z" );
data.put("endTime", "2023-08-26T12:00:00Z");
data.put("datapoints", datapoints);
info headers;
response = invokeUrl
[
    url: "https://horti-api.priva.com/api/sites/[site_id]/data"
    type: POST
parameters: data
    headers: headers
];
info response;
```

I've tried adjusting the headers:

replacing "content-type: application/*+json" with "content-type: application/json".

Have also tried posting the "data" as a map using:

```
jdata = Map();
jdata.put("data",data);
```

Have also tried posting as

```
jdata.put("JSONString",data);
```

Comment: A friend finally helped me troubleshoot this and I am sharing the details here for anyone facing a similar issue.

Basically, the after checking the server side response, the content format being sent by the call was being modified by the invoke_url function - which was corrected for by specifying a parameter for content type in the url call.
<pre>
    content_type = "application/*+json";
 response = invokeurl
 [
  url: target_url
  type: POST
  headers: headers
  content-type: content_type
  parameters: data.tostring()
 ];
<code>

Answer (score 0):

The [invokeUrl](https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/webhook/invokeurl-api-task.html) method overrides the content-type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the default value. Explicitly pass `content-type:` as a parameter with the "application/*+json" to the invokeUrl method.